# Launch Application from background with internet Availability

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification, reachability

Is it possible to get a notification (that launches the app) when the network gets available?What I want is my application to update its contents as soon the internet gets available.The only way I can think of is to send a push from the server once is a while (may be once a day)and that tell the user it might be a good idea to get yourself synchronized.

Comment: The application can come in fore-ground only when user tried to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently impossible if your background task scope is limited to that feature. The only way you could do this is if you had some other legitimate reason to become a background app (aka VOIP or GPS) and run reachability checks every `X` minutes, and then post a `UILocalNotification` that allows the user optionally open the app (you cannot programmatically open your app yourself).

Comment: Even if apple rejects my application,still would there be any way I could get hold of the process that gets triggers once the network is available

Comment: No, not unless you had a jailbroken phone and did some system modding (disclaimer, I have no experience with jailbroken development).